# Having issue with adding the string a plist file

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, plist

I have a plist file in my application which a table view loads its object. I need to save a string when user types a text in `textfield` and taps the save button, here is my code , the log shows me the correct string but the table doesn't reload and plist doesn't add anything !

```
     NSString *rootPath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath=[rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"users.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist_dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

if(plist_dict==nil)
{
    plist_dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
[plist_dict setObject:_username.text forKey:@"username"];

[plist_dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];


[_tableView reloadData];
```

And here is my default plist file :

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>username</key>
    <array>
        <string>Instagram</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Check and report the return value from `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:]` to see if that is the issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe Would you check my edited Q ?

Comment: I think the code before was fine; writing the plist as an array is OK.  What you must do, however, is check what `writeToFile:` returns and write an log entry in case of failure in order to narrow-down where the error originates.

Comment: @trojanfoe When I log `plist_dict` it gives me the correct result :     `username = xxx;` for example but it doesn't refresh tableview and add to plist file , by the way how can I check and report `[NSArray writeToFile:atomically:] ` ?

Comment: Using an `if` statement and a call to `NSLog()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString *rootPath=[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath=[rootPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appSetting.plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist_dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

if(plist_dict==nil)
{
    plist_dict =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
}
[plist_dict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:status] forKey:@"isLoggedIn"];

[plist_dict writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

use this code. its working for me. hope it will help you.

Comment: still doesn't add anything ! I don't have any `key`  in my plist

Comment: you should use key otherwise how will access the value

Comment: I just add key but still doesn't work ! check my edited question